# share database of same apps on android

Tags: android, database

If we have two different mobile users for same android application, and each of them is updating the some data in database table. I want to know how they can know each other's updates and how can they share a database.

How is sharing and syncing of database implemented on android?

Comment: Make a ContentProvider: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html